# How to communicate with own Android Service through ADB?

Tags: android, android-service, adb

I want to get some information out of Service that is already running on the device. I know that system services use **dumpsys** for such purposes. Is there a way to provide some information to dumpsys?

There is also thed dropbox service (`dumpsys dropbox`) but I'm not sure how to use it.

I was also thinking about sending a broadcast that will cause the Service to create a file on SD card but it's looks like a bad solution.

Comment: Unix domain sockets might be interesting.  For simple things, a broadcast and dump to logcat (that you could recover with grep) could work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to use `dumpsys` you need to implement the [`dump(FileDescriptor fd, PrintWriter writer, String[] args)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#dump(java.io.FileDescriptor,%20java.io.PrintWriter,%20java.lang.String[])) method in your service.